# How do I import into a Channel Images field using DataGrab?

Tags: channel-images, datagrab, migration

I'm using XML and DataGrab to move our blog posts to a new home. All the other fields are migrating correctly, but I can't get the Channel Images field to use a image url that's being supplied by my XML file. Is there another way to do this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

When I looked at this about 6 months ago the unfortunate answer was it can't be done :(

http://brandnewbox.co.uk/forums/viewthread/666/

They did show interest in adding support but doesn't look to be added yet.